# How to catch exception thrown from Future[HttpResponse] scala

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am new to scala. I am using the HTTP-client of scala to hit another server. Where the response returned is Future[HttpResponse]. Here is something that I have:

```
pathPrefix("run") {
    post {
        entity(as[InputRequest]) { inputRequest =>
            complete {
               runService(inputRequest)
            }
        }
    }
}

def runService(inputRequest:InputRequest) : Future[HttpResponse] = {
    val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive  ~> unmarshal[HttpResponse]
    val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Post("some-hostname", inputRequest)
    ~> addCredentials(BasicHttpCredentials("user", "pass"))

    response
}
```

So if something fails(like 500 internal server error) from response, How to catch its exception?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to do it:

Using rejection handler directive:

```
handleRejections(/*your custom rejection handler || default*/) {
  pathPrefix("run") {
  ...
}
```

Or `recover` `Future`:

```
response.recover {
  case t => // t is Throwable, do something with it
}
```

The return type of your function `def runService(inputRequest:InputRequest) : Future[HttpResponse]` will then change depending on what your recover evaluates to

Comment: OKay. How to work on second option, can you please suggest any example

Comment: a simple google returs results like: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/concurrency-with-scala-futures-tutorials-examples http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-9-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-futures/ So many good examples